# Acceleration using Game Time

Tags: c#, opentk

I was wondering if there is any elapsed gametime method that I could add acceleration to a entity. I want to use something like XNA's elapsed gametime code. The amount of seconds that pass by through each frame is all I need to get acceleration working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `GameWindow`, you can use the `FrameEventArgs` from the `UpdateFrame` and `RenderFrame` events.

```
class MyGame : GameWindow
{
    double seconds;
    Vector3 position;

    protected override void OnUpdateFrame(object sender, FrameEventArgs e)
    {
        // e.Time is the elapsed time from the previous UpdateFrame event
        // in seconds
        seconds += e.Time;
        position = new Vector3(
            (float)Math.Cos(seconds),
            (float)Math.Sin(seconds),
            1.0f);
    }
}
```